# Dynamically change the drawable

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have an app that builds a route on top of a map image. I know that res/drawable is compiled by the program beforehand, but still: I have code that creates an xml file inside the program files.
Example:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="3840dp"
android:height="2160dp"
android:viewportWidth="3840"
android:viewportHeight="2150">
<path
    android:pathData = "M3433,1310 L2964,1310 L2964,950 L1860,950 L1860,1870"
    android:strokeLineCap="round"
    android:strokeLineJoin="round"
    android:strokeWidth = "20"
    android:strokeColor = "@color/route_color"/>
<path
    android:fillColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:pathData="M1860,1670C1821.3,1670 1790,1701.3 1790,1740c0,52.5 70,130 70,130s70,-77.5 70,-130c0,-38.7 -31.3,-70 -70,-70zM1860,1765c-13.8,0 -25,-11.2 -25,-25s11.2,-25 25,-25 25,11.2 25,25 -11.2,25 -25,25z"/>
</vector>
```

How would I apply this xml to take advantage of

```
val res = Drawable.createFromPath("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.gubkinmap/files/map_route.xml")
root.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView).setBackgroundResource(res)
```

P.S. Sorry for the nonsense, this is my first app

Answer (score 0):

I think it is difficult to change and read the drawable.

In these cases, using an image loading framework such as Glide should be easy to achieve.

For example, Glide publishes a sample that loads SVG from the web.
https://github.com/bumptech/glide/tree/master/samples/svg

Just change it to read the local SVG file that generated it.